# Confused with DispatchSource availability

Tags: ios, xcode, availability

The [documentation online](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsource) says iOS 7.0+:

[image]

but the Xcode documentation says iOS 10.0+:
[image]

I'm so confused with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's iOS 7.0+.

FYI, in Xcode 9.2, it correctly reports iOS 7.0+ in the built-in help, too:

[image]

It's undoubtedly just a mistake in the documentation in Xcode 8.2.1. I wouldn't worry about it.